# Matching id with click element id or neatest parent id of Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML:

```
...included jquery
<div id="step1">
  .. there are more child div
  <div id="step2">
    .. more child div
    <div id="step3">
      Selection 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class-1">
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Section 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...Some more neatest div and element
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
  let idNo = event.target.id;
  if(idNo == "step1"){
    # Do something
  }else{
    console.log(idNo); //print "step3"
    # Do others
  }
});
```

I'm trying to check if user click div which id is "step1" then do something. But event.target always contain child div information like in this case div which id is "step3".
How can i check if clicking item have any neatest parent div with id "step1"
Remember my content is dynamic so i can't set up click listener like `$("step1").click();`

Comment: Why are steps nested inside of empty divs? This isn't going to work if you can't modify the HTML structure.

Comment: You can think there are multiple child inside of every div. I just show this as demo of my problem

Answer (score 2):

We can write a simple function to get all the parent ids of an element:

```js
function getParentIds(el) {
  let ids = [];
  
  while (el.parentNode) {
    let parentId = el.parentNode.id;
    if (parentId)
      ids.push(parentId);
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  
  return ids;
}

// sample usage
let element = document.querySelector('#three');
console.log(getParentIds(element));
// output: ['two', 'one']
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div id="three">
      Sample
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We can then attach this function our target nodes to determine their nearest parents (assuming there are no intermediate ids).

```
$('step1 *').click(function() {
  var parentIds = getParentIds(this);
  var nearestParent = parentIds[parentIds.length - 1];

  if (nearestParent == 'step1')) {/* do something for immediate children of step 1 */}
  else if (nearestParent == 'step2') {/* do something for immediate children of step 2 */}
  else { /* nearestParent is 'step3' */ }
})
```